# Glue Pyspark: How to set exception handling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I created a AWS Glue jobs, and set them to work five minutes each. These jobs capture the data from particular S3 buckets / Glue tables.

```
data = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options...

data = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog...
```

In this situation, when there is no data in S3 buckets / Glue tables, Glue jobs will get errors.

I need to keep Glue jobs work five minutes each, and would like to avoid error when the S3 buckets / Glue tables are empty. Does anyone know how can I set exception handling for the Glue jobs?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're after, but it's easy enough to do the following to avoid an error: `DataSource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "database", table_name = "table_name", transformation_ctx = "DataSource0")` then `if DataSource0.count() > 0: ... transformations, etc`

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to avoid the error.